# Javascript:Custom print button in mail templates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know is there any options to include a 'PRINT' button and the functionality to print a particular div or the message body itself.

Comment: You can call `window.print()` but you should expect this not to work in at least some mail clients.

Comment: yeah major problem is with gmail. I have tried both  window.print() and  javascript:print() but when the mail is reached gmail both are seems to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. JavaScript is not supported in emails (thank God!).

Also, why do you even want to do that? Every email programm has that functionality already.

Edit: OK, there are some [exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-mail_clients) that actually support JavaScript. But this does not mean you should even think about adding JavaScript to your emails.

Comment: Its a requirement from my client to include a print button, thats why. Is there exists any possible alternatives?

Comment: No there are no alternatives. Also, please talk to your client and explain him that this is neither possible nor useful. You should not blindly follow any wish of your clients.